# The app opens and closes 3 times while starting appium

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I'm experiencing something strange and can't find any information on the net about it.
I'm starting to develop automation for the iOS OS app.

I wrote some capabilities for appium (Attachment below the post).

When I run the code in intellij idea, the simulator opens, app install begins and after it WebDrivetAgent install too.
Then, the app opens and closes 3 times, literally every second, and then it closes.
Anyone seen a case like this?
Attaching logs from the server

The test annotation just for check that the driver opens.

```
@Test
public void SetUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "12.4");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 8 Plus");
    cap.setCapability("app","/Users/mykll/Desktop/Payload/Leumi-Loyalty-MESIRA.app");
    cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
    cap.setCapability("fullReset",false);

    driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
}
```

There is some logs from appium:

```
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"value":"Failed to launch com.leumi.leumiLoyalty application","sessionId":"4FAF5EAB-ABD2-4505-B01B-09E298A49B4C","status":13}
[MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 13 to UnknownError
[XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session (An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to launch com.leumi.leumiLoyalty application). Retrying...
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1565026119270 (20:28:39 GMT+0300 (EEST))
[XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"com.leumi.leumiLoyalty","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}}
```

Comment: Which version of appium java-client and appium server are you using? Are you able to start the app manually?

Comment: Hi @AndiCover, yeap the app is starting manually.
I'm using java client version 7.1.0,

and my appium server is v1.13.0.

In additional, my dependencies are:

Junit 4.13-beta-3.
selenium java 3.141.59.
Using maven , intellij idea.

Comment: Try upgrading appium server to v1.14.0.

Comment: Can you also attach the device log? (it can be enabled by showIOSLog capability)

Comment: Did you find a resolution to your issue @Michael